# Examples for TagManager API v2 in Java

Tags: java, google-tag-manager

I am researching about using the TagManager API v2 in Java.

I am trying to get a very basic stand-alone Java app running which just gets all containers in my account and possibly modifies one of the containers (e.g. by adding a tag).

I found a bunch of links on the web but I am not quite sure which one is applicable.

I have already generated a client_secrets.json.
Also, I have the correct pom.xml, I think.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-tagmanager</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev2-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/tagmanager/v2

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/tagmanager/v2/java/latest/

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup

Are there any working examples or step-by-step instructions on how to build and run it?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. -> *GTM team, please help me with some working example and step by step instructions how to build and run it.*

Comment: I don't ask for any recommendations. I am using GTM. I am just trying to find my way and find a good basic example in Java. GTM team recommends we ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Given the instructions at [API Client Library Instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/tagmanager/v2) and a directory structure for gradle like so:

```
./
./build.gradle
./src
./src/main
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/Quickstart.java
./src/main/resources
./src/main/resources/client_secret.json
```

$cat build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Quickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tagmanager:v2-rev2-1.22.0'
}
```

$cat src/main/java/Quickstart.java

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.tagmanager.TagManagerScopes;
import com.google.api.services.tagmanager.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.tagmanager.TagManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "TagManager API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/tagmanager-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/tagmanager-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final Set<String> SCOPES = TagManagerScopes.all();

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized TagManager client service.
     * @return an authorized Tagmanager client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static TagManager getTagManagerService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new TagManager.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        TagManager service = getTagManagerService();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        ListAccountsResponse result = service.accounts().list()
             .execute();
        List<Account> accounts = result.getAccount();
        if (accounts == null || accounts.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No accounts found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Accounts:");
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", account.getAccountId(), account.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To run:

```
$gradle -q run
```